# Waiting for a signal (POSIX)

Tags: c, signals, posix

I'm doing a classic "waiting for signal" situation. I'm basically waiting for `SIGUSR1` which is sent from a child process which was covered using `execlp()`. Even though the signal does get caught using `sigaction()`, the process never moves on from `sigwaitinfo()`.
Here's the code (because it is not so long, I've kept the not so relevant stuff but I'm basically sending data to the child process using a pipe. I am also aware that I'm not checking return values but I've checked, no errors)

```
void DataThread::runWaiting()
{ 
    while(1)
    {
        string data;
        Bottle* bot = inPort.read();
        if (bot != NULL) 
        { 
            data = bot->toString();
            cout << "I'm about to send : " << data << endl;
            fprintf(fromYarpPipe,"%s\n",data.c_str()); 
            fflush(fromYarpPipe);

            sigemptyset( &sigact.sa_mask );
            sigact.sa_handler = catcher;
            sigact.sa_flags = 0;
            sigaction( SIGUSR1, &sigact, NULL );

            sigset_t mask;
            sigemptyset(&mask);
            sigaddset(&mask,SIGUSR1);
            cout << "Got this far and I'm " << getpid() << endl;
            sigwaitinfo(&mask,NULL);
            cout << "I just moved on !" << endl;
        }
    }
}

void catcher( int sig ) 
{
    cout << "Got some signal : "<< sig << endl;;
}
```

I get the following output each time i `kill -USR1 pid` but not the line following the `sigwaitinfo()`...

```
Got some signal : 10
```

Comment: Use a pipe instead of a signal.  Either create the pipe pre-fork and have the child write into it, or, if available, use `signalfd`.

Comment: Hmmmm "I've checked, no errors" implies that you do not realize that things can happen differently each time the process executes.

Comment: Performance wise, creating a second file does not seem like such a good idea. The context is that I'm getting data at high speed (and possibly in a large ammount) from a sensor, sending it through a pipe. Because the receiving child process might not be fast enough, it sends a signal to its father when it is ready to receive some more. I need something really light... Do you know why this does not work ?

Comment: What I meant by "I've checked, no erros" means that I've been on this for a few hours and even though this issue has happened 100% of the time, it is clearly not linked to the return values of these functions. After writing 100 times the testing of the return value of these functions, I stopped bothering...

Comment: It's tedious, but you should check all return values, always. And `cerr` when they fail. You never know what can go wrong, especially at this low level. If your code gets too cluttered by all the error checking, just write a macro.

Comment: Creating a pipe does not imply creating a file.  Writing a byte through a pipe is *much* cleaner than using signals for IPC, and is indeed quite light on overhead.  Don't rule it out until you've benchmarked.

Comment: There's no need for you to do anything!!  If the child is not able to keep up with the data, the writer of the pipe (the parent) will block on a write.  Data will be lost, but that will happen in any case.  The operating system already does all the work you are trying to implement.  The parent writes data, if the child isn't ready, then the parent blocks.  If you need to know about that, set the fd non-blocking and the parent will get an error on the write.  You do not need to have the child notify the parent explicitly.

Comment: I must admit I have not benchmarked but I thought that there was nothing lighter than a signal. I might try that if I can't make this work.

Comment: As for the "keeping up" goes, I'll try to explain this in more depth. The parent does block when the pipe is "full", but when the child process gets back on its feet and reads some data, it reads some old stuff and not the freshest data coming from the father process. It creates a growing delay that is not acceptable in the program. This was not benchmark but easily visible by just printing the input and the output of the pipe (growing delay reaching fast several seconds)

Comment: You just need to use a non-blocking write on the parent's side and let the parent discard the data or farm it out to another worker (or increase the speed of the processing to keep up!)

Comment: If you do want a notification that the child is ready to read, let the operating system tell you: just select/poll/epoll on the file descriptor and it will tell you whether or not the pipe can take any more data (which is almost exactly the same as saying that the child is able to consume more data)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you must

```
    sigprocmask( SIG_BLOCK, &waitset, NULL );
```

after the `sigaddset`.

Comment: This does not change the result (yes I changed `&waitset`to `&mask`)

Comment: Strange. I compared your code to mine and I don't see anything wrong with it. It works for me and gives the exepcted result.

Comment: I just tested your code, and it works for me. Maybe the problem is somewhere else? I run it from main without fork or exec and so on, so basically it should work. I just removed the irrelevant part with fprintf and the bot. Did you try to set a breakpoint after wait?

Comment: It is indeed extremely weird, it is in the context of a much larger program in my case but I don't see why it should matter... I've tried with `sigwait()` as well. `sigtimedwait()` will allow moving on, but only after the timeout. Could it be because I'm in the context of a C++ class ? Why should a breakpoint help since the program gets stuck at this point anyway ? To check some variables ? If so which ones ?

Comment: To confirm that the it really is stuck and not just the cout is suppressed for some reason. Yeah, I know if the catcher can print, so should your main code, but it doesn't hurt to check. I guess, if you checked with the timed wait, then this is probably not the case though. In my case I'm using pselect to wait, because I'm watiting for socket and use the signal to switch logging level. However I also tried it in my mainloop with sigwait and it still worked for me as well as the SSCE from your code. And I'm also using a class, so this shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Checking the waitset before you enter sigwait might be a good idea. If the memory got overwritten somehow, it may have different values, than you anticipate, so it's worth to check this.

Comment: @DwProd: About using `cout` in this context: it's buffered, so when you're dealing with multiple processes/threads, its output might be misleading. When I worked with signals, pipes and its friends in a distributed systems college course, we sprintf'ed to a char array and used the `write` syscall to write to standard output; that syscall was unbuffered, i.e. it flushed right away. I believe you can set a flag for `cout` so that it does unbuffered output, but I didn't try it.

Comment: Since you're using a socket, would you consider it to be on the same level performance wise ? Would you recommand it ?It does have the advantage to be bi-directional, thus replacing the pipe+signal by a socket.

Comment: Well I, I can't say that using a socket is better, because my process has only a low amount of data, so performance is not a problem for me. I'm using also pipes to monitor childprocesses and transfer the result via the sockets to a remote and it looks fast enough for me, but I don't know about your requirements.